# How to reverse a number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry if the question sounded uneducated, I am in no way a math expert, but I know enough algebra to get around and stuff. So what I want to know is if i have a number, lets say `6` on a scale from `1` to `10` how would I get the opposite of that number compared to my scale, so `4`. So, `7` would equal `3` and `9` would equal `1` so on so fourth. I am doing this on a scale of 1 to 500. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or the title sounded stupid.
(p.s. I am also sorry if I used the wrong tags, I don't know what this would be classified as)

Comment: consider $f(x)=500-x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that, for the example you gave, the scale would really be $0 \dots 10$. Otherwise $10$ wouldn't have an opposite. So, If $n$ is the number, $r$ is the reverse of the number, $s$ is the scale, and it starts at $0$, then $r=s-n$.

So in your case, $r=500-n$.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain your 1 to 500 scale (s). Simply subtract your number (n) from scale+1 to get its reverse (r).

So using the equation r=s+1-n, the numbers 1, 2, 3 ... 498, 499, 500 become 500, 499, 498 ... 3, 2, 1.

For example:

• Where number is 1, its reverse is 500+1-1=500.

• Where number is 2, its reverse is 500+1-2=499.

• Where number is 3, its reverse is 500+1-3=498.

...

• Where number is 498, its reverse is 500+1-498=3.

• Where number is 499, its reverse is 500+1-499=2.

• Where number is 500, its reverse is 500+1-500=1.